# Teaching platform on AWS Serverless Architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-serverless

I am trying to build a **secure teaching platform** in AWS. I am planning to host my videos on vooplayer (now spotlightr) and just have the front end web page with authentication, few pages to display the course videos. I am thinking I can host the website on **S3**, use **Cognito** for authentication and authorization and store user data and course data i.e. video urls in **DynamoDB** and may be few **Lambda functions** and **API Gateway**.

Am I going in the right direction in choosing this **serverless architecture** for the use case?

I am just going to store few collection in DynamoDB

- User - email, name
- Course - course id, course name, external (vooplayer/spotlightr) video url, cost
- Purchase - email, course, date of purchase, amount paid, currency
- Activity - email, course id, started at, valid till

I estimate there will be 100 users in next 6 months, may be more if things goes well.

I hope storing this data shouldn't cost much in the long run.

I chose **vooplayer/spotlightr** for their encryption and making it really difficult for malicious users to download and play the videos unlike other popular video streaming platforms we know.

I hope streaming video from external hosting sites with front end hosted on AWS won't get charged. Please correct me and point me in the right direction otherwise.

I know I could use off-the-shelf products like Udemy, Teachable, etc. I am between jobs and want to build something and learn something new while building it. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverless is a good solution for most problems, and it is entirely feasible for your solution.

Most of the services you list are included in the [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc) of AWS.

You should be able to find pricing information for the services on their pricing pages:

- [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)
- [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/pricing/)
- [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/)
- [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/)
- [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/pricing/)

Comment: Thank you Chris for your reply, 
I am still looking for an answer for this one particularly "I hope streaming video from an externally hosted site (vooplayer/spotlightr) with front end hosted on AWS won't get charged. Please correct me and point me in the right direction otherwise." I don't if I'll be charged for data read from external host when someone plays the video using embed code posted on the web page hosted on S3

Comment: If the video is hosted externally and accessed in the users browser then you will not be charged. As its an embeddable widget the browser handles the connection to that resource not AWS. :)